# how can i extract total forum_question and fourm_answer count as subject wise in mysql i have below mysql structure

Tags: mysql, sql

forum_question :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `subject_id` (`subject_id`,`student_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
)
```

forum_answer table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_answer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `faculty_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `question_id` (`question_id`,`faculty_id`),
  KEY `faculty_id` (`faculty_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

and subject table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this edited query, I am sure this will work

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(que.id) AS totalQuestions, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(forum_answer.id)) 
    FROM 
        forum_answer 
    WHERE 
        forum_answer.question_id = que.id 
    GROUP BY que.id) 
    AS totalAns 
FROM 
    forum_question que 
    INNER JOIN 
    subject sub 
    ON (que.subject_id = sub.id) 
 WHERE 
    que.id > 0 
 GROUP BY sub.id
```

Comment: but how can i get subject name

Comment: SELECT COUNT(que.id) AS  totalQuestions,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(forum_answer.id))  
 FROM forum_answer 
 WHERE forum_answer.question_id = que.id
 GROUP BY que.id) 
 AS totalAns ,sub.name
 FROM forum_question que 
 INNER JOIN subject sub ON 
 (que.subject_id = sub.id) 
 WHERE que.id > 0 GROUP BY sub.id

Answer (score 0):

If by total you mean the total amount of rows, you can do the following:

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_question WHERE subject_id=YOURSUBJECT`
```

if you want just all rows, remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: i need question and answer count not just question count

Answer (score 0):

Please you can try this Query

```
SELECT
subject.name AS subject_name,
count(forum_question.id) AS total_question,
(SELECT count(forum_answer.id)
FROM
forum_answer
WHERE
forum_answer.question_id =  forum_question.id) AS total_answer
FROM
subject
Inner Join forum_question ON subject.id = forum_question.subject_id
GROUP BY subject.id
```

Sorry it was my mistake. now I edited the query and hope it will work for you